# How to enable Prompt Password feature in Chrome and IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsp, google-chrome

I have a login page which has username and password developed in HTML and i has enabled the autocomplete="on" for both fields. It works fine for Firefox but it does not work in Chrome and IE8.I have done the settings in Content tab "User names and Passwords forms", but still it wont ask me "Remeber Password..".

Code:

```
   <form method="post" action="sample.jsp" id="form_connection" onsubmit="return loginSubmit();">

                                <a href="#" class="buttonConnection connection_off" tabindex="3"><span class="tr text">connection</span></a>
                                <div class="error_on"><span class="tr">errorFields</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                                     <!--Style it according to your need -->
                                     <input type="submit" value=" Login ">
                </form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Remove autocomplete="on", because you don't need it, and for all we know it's making it not work. 2) You sure you didn't select "never ask for this site"? All modern browsers will ask you if you want to remember the username/password. Clear temporary/history files, and try again.

Comment: @Shea i have removed autocomplete, cleared all history and files, still i didnt get this alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I got the answer, its IE8 feature which restricts the prompting if you use lang(i18) inside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome
settings > advance settings > manage saved passwords > never saved

Delete your page address from there

Comment: i have done all these already my page address is not there in that list :(, thanks for reply

Comment: Are you using these input fields inside <form> tag ?
If not use <form> tag

Comment: i have pasted from <form> to </form>

Comment: In javascript validate function, are you returning true after validation is done and form is ready to be sent?

Comment: Use <input type="submit" > 
redirect to valid url and it will prompt

Comment: can you please edit my code with sample with the solution you suggested.

Comment: try this
go to internet options > content >settings > check username and passwords in forms

Answer (score 0):

See this post for an extensive list of reasons why you might not be prompted to save your password: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx

There's nothing wrong with the markup you've shown above, so the most likely explanation is that either you once clicked "No" when prompted to save a password for this page, or your browser settings are configured not to prompt.

Comment: i have gone through the above link still i am not getting prompt password :(